# Android Studio generates unwanted java source folder references to .iml file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, cmake

I'm building an android app with both Java and C++ files.

I use CMake to compile my C++ code into a shared library.
My CMake file uses some cross-platform code from our master platform framework.

The problem is that for some reason Android Studio generates faulty source directory inclusions. I think it is because of the CMake file since it is the only place I reference the whole directory.

The main problem is that

```
<sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../../../../../PLATFORM/src"
```

Adds that folder (and everything under it) as JAVA source folder, which includes all kinds of stuff I don't want to be included. I only want CMake to access those folders while compiling the C++ library. My .java files are copied under the solution dir.

Any ideas on how to prevent .java sources being included from outside the solution?

CMakeLists.txt (Used to compile the c++ library)

```
file(GLOB src_platform "../../../../../../../../../../PLATFORM/src/platform.cpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE src_jpeg "../../../../../../../../../../PLATFORM/src/ext/jpeg/*.c")
file(GLOB_RECURSE src_png "../../../../../../../../../../PLATFORM/src/ext/png/*.c")

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        native-library

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        ${src_platform}
        ${src_jpeg}
        ${src_png})
```

app.iml file (IDEA solution file, generated and used by Android Studio)

```
<component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_8">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/javac/debug/compileDebugJavaWithJavac/classes" />
    <output-test url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/javac/debugUnitTest/compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac/classes" />
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../../../../../PLATFORM/src">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../../../../../PLATFORM/src" isTestSource="false" />
        </content>
    [...]
</component>
```

Comment: Not an answer, but why would you write paths like that? There's a lot better alternatives than using highly relative paths that will break if the build system makes any changes to folder structure

Comment: Such as using variables to define their locations? Would need to have a place to define them somewhere. Could work, but might add some variable creep as well.

Comment: That for one, yeah. Including pre-defined path constants created by CMake